# Flex/AIR and AlivePDF: Ordered and unordered lists

Tags: apache-flex, list, air, alivepdf

Is it possible to export ordered and unordered lists using AlivePDF? (Or is there another client side PDF generating library which can do this?)

I'm building an AIR app which should be able to export slides with speaker notes a la Power Point, but the lists have got me stumped.

Comment: You could export as an image to the PDF, but I guess you want the text to be selectable, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like there is no native lists support in AlivePDF. You can try:

1. Add such support since [AlivePDF is open-source](http://alivepdf.bytearray.org/)
2. Emulate lists with text by using [non-latin symbols](http://www.utf8-chartable.de/) for list dots

Comment: Thanks. I'm leaning towards option 2 now, since it's really close to my deadline. The trickiness is in getting the second line of each list item have the same indent as the first, otherwise it would be a simple matter to insert a bullet at the beginning of each item.

Comment: @J_A_X: Anything wrong with waiting a day to see if there are other suggestions? Don't worry, the rep will be awarded.